# What's the best way to debug and enhance the speed of your server?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

My server has been running slightly slower than normal.

I was wondering what strategies I could do to evaluate the speed of my server, and enhance it

This question covers database interaction, I/O, and anything else someone might need to know

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2005 and above? Do you have a baseline for your Normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a methodical approach like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). Its a proven successful performance troubleshooting methodology that  *will* guide you down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to provide some more information if you want any decent answers. Example:

- What kind of server is it. (what do you server: web, ftp etc)
- What Applications does it run
- How is the user situation.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

As @nenne mentioned its hard to tell how to improve the performance of your servers with such little information. But if you are on SQL SErver 2005 and above I suggest you use the right DMV's and start checking for the top 5 or 10 most expensive queries and also check the wait stats: Is sql server waiting on IO, CPU or memory? Is there any blocking issues? Is your  statistics updated? You can use profiler and Perfmon to investigate the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said before this is very open ended but if you have noticed a decline in performance and have no maintenance routine you may want to look at rebuilding indexes (all or just those that require it dependant on maintenance Window available and effort). Also Updating statistics as Dani mentioned.

Anything interesting in event viewer, any hardware that might not report errors in there so will require you to use vendor supplied tools.

If you've still got issues look into perfmon counters and dmv's as well as profiler.

You could start worse places than http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Performance_Tuning

Cheers